# Can I force Objectify to use getters and setters?

Tags: objectify

Is it possible to make Objectify use my getters and setters in my pojos/beans? I have debugged and even if my fields are private and I have correctly named, public getters and setters, they are never used. Objectify seemingly just reads and writes directly to the private fields.

This makes a lot of things harder than they need to be, especially when it comes to collections that I want to declare as final, since I do not want to create new ArrayLists etc. all the time.

So, is it possible to let Objectify use my getters and setters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it uses reflection to set the properties as fields directly, at least in Ofy4

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Objectify deliberately uses fields rather than using java properties.